# AUTOHOTKEY: Problem with code which suspend script after clicking key and unsuspend it after clicking 2 another keys. Doing 2 things at the same time

Tags: loops, autohotkey, suspend

In game chat start with t key and I want that after pressing t on keyboard my script will be suspend and I will can normally write on chat but if I press enter or esc my script will be unsuspended (esc - close chat, enter - send message on chat).

I have problem with this code:

```
t::
Suspend On
Loop
{
    GetKeyState, state, Enter, P
    GetKeyState, state2, Escape, P
    if (state = Enter){
        Suspend Off 
        break
    }   
    else if (state2 = Escape){
        Suspend Off
        break
    }   
}
return
```

Main problem with this code is loop which not work, and I don't know how to repair it or replace it something more useful or better solution.

Another problem is t key which work but I must click it 2 times, why? First click suspends script, second click runs chat. I want after clicking 1 time t key chat will run and script will suspend. I want the same with enter and esc, to make 2 functions at the same time (enter - unsuspends script and send message on chat, esc - close chat and unsuspends script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the usage of the (deprecated legacy) GetKeyState command, but I must say, the whole solution could be implemented a lot better.
The output value of the command doesn't contain key names, it contains `D` for down, or `U` for up, as stated in the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm). And also you'd need to `"quote"` your strings.

And the problem with your <kbd>T</kbd> key not working on the first press, is of course because you have a hotkey that is capturing the press of the T key.
To not consume the T key press when the hotkey runs, you want to use the `~` modifier<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde)</sup>.

---

But anyway, I think a better implementation would be just that a press of the keys simply suspends/unsuspends.
Like so:

```
~t::Suspend, On

~Enter::
~Esc::Suspend, Off
```

---

As a bonus:
The usage of `#IfWinActive`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)</sup> might be desirable so the hotkeys only work when your game is active.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe ExeOfMyGame.exe
~t::Suspend, On

~Enter::
~Esc::Suspend, Off
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works is 50%  not in 100%. When I click t my script is suspended and chat is on, but when I write t on chat my script is unsuspended. And when I write another t is suspended again. I wanted when I click t, only clicking enter/esc will unsuspend script. I am making a macro for the game and it is protection for the chat, after clicking hotkeys my makro will do nothing when chat will be opened.

Comment: Oops, I mixed up my thoughts, of course ESC was supposed to be used instead of `t`. Makes the script even easier. I'll edit now.

Comment: Thanks I stopped on this version of code:
~t::Suspend, On
    Suspend, Permit
    if (A_IsSuspended){
  ~Enter::Suspend, Off
  ~Escape::Suspend, Off
 }
return

But in my script I have hotkeys which makes a Send Keys combination to my game and after I add this code upper/code from your anwser any hotkeys don't want to work before I suspend script and after I suspend and unsuspend it. Any help why is it like that? I also add that on top of my script I added #IfWinActive, ahk_exe GTA5.exe and at the bottom #IfWinActive.

Comment: Ok I made a checkbox in gui and added hotkey to it and label where I put this code and it work but maybe you will tell me better solution.

Comment: I change code to this: 
~t::
    Suspend On
    Loop
        if (GetKeyState("Enter", "P") || GetKeyState("Escape", "P"))
            break
    Suspend Off
return

Why? Because in your code is that problem when I suspend script manually and click enter/esc it unsuspend I needed after click t it suspend and only enter/esc will unsuspend it. When I manually suspend it in my code enter/esc do not unsuspend it. BUT THANKS A LOT <3

Answer (score 0):

I change code to this:

```
~t::
    Suspend On
    Loop
        if (GetKeyState("Enter", "P") || GetKeyState("Escape", "P"))
            break
    Suspend Off
return
```

Why? Because in **@0x464e** code was that problem when I suspended script manually and click enter / esc it unsuspended it, I needed after click T it suspend and only enter / esc will unsuspend it. When I manually suspend it in code which is above enter / esc do not unsuspend it.